# expo react native: match the current date to the list of deadline in the background and notify the user if matched

Tags: react-native, expo

I need help on how to implement the local notification this way:

I have a list of dates/deadlines in array example(
Deadlines[January 2, 2022, January 3, 2022, January 5, 2022] ),  that I wanted to compare if the current date(today) is matched to the deadline
Everyday it will check in the background(app is close) if it’s match then I wanted to notify the user 2 times at a specific hour which is 7am and 12pm,
I can’t find it in expo or any example on How to do that?  I tried to use the DailyNotificationTrigger but I don’t think its what I need because it’s notifying the user even though there is no deadline on that particular day, please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

my update on this is to use the built-in calendar of the device and using the expo calendar library I was able to fill those gaps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).